# jQuery Mobile - Google navigation - Directions Service - Current position identification

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a JQuery Mobile website that people use with their Android device.
(This website mainly deals with clients information.)
I've been looking to integrate a "GET DIRECTION" feature.
I was wondering if it's possible to open Google Navigation app (because it can be used as a GPS, voice navigation) with the current location and one client's address through JQM ?
If not, does anyone has any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

The official W3C site informs about the [W3C Geolocation working group](http://www.w3.org/2008/geolocation/) and the milestones that have been set.

You can find [here](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html) a fresh (May 2012) W3C draft proposal for the Geolocation API.

Below you can find a sample working example that I created. The code finds the current position and provides a direction service. There is a textbox where you can write the target destination and a button which "Get Directions". When you click the button a list at the end of the page is filled with the directions.

You can modify it in order to fit your needs. Furthermore you can find more information about the directions service in the [Google Map JavaScript API Directions Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions).

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
        <title>jQuery mobile with Google maps</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&language=en"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var map;
            var currentPosition;
            var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();         
            var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

            function initialize(lat, lon)
            {
                currentPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);

                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
                   zoom: 15,
                   center: currentPosition,
                   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                 });

                directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
                //directionsDisplay.setPanel($("#instructions-content"));

                 var currentPositionMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: currentPosition,
                    map: map,
                    title: "Current position"
                });

                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                google.maps.event.addListener(currentPositionMarker, 'click', function() {
                    infowindow.setContent("Current position: latitude: " + lat +" longitude: " + lon);
                    infowindow.open(map, currentPositionMarker);
                });
            }

            function locError(error) 
            {
                alert("The position or the map could not be loaded.");
            }

            function locSuccess(position) 
            {
                initialize(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            }

            $(document).ready(function() 
            {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locSuccess, locError);

                $("#directions-button").click(function(){
                    var targetDestination = $("#target-dest").val();

                    if (currentPosition && currentPosition != '' && targetDestination && targetDestination != '')
                    {
                        var request = {
                            origin:currentPosition, 
                            destination:targetDestination,
                            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode["DRIVING"]
                        };

                        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                                directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("instructions-content"));
                                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response); 

                                // For debuging reasons uncomment
                                /*
                                var myRoute = response.routes[0].legs[0];
                                for (var i = 0; i < myRoute.steps.length; i++) {
                                  alert(myRoute.steps[i].instructions);
                                }*/
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert("The target destination is empty or the current position could not be located.");
                    }
                }); 
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="basic-map" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1><a data-ajax="false" href="/">jQuery mobile with Google maps v3</a> examples</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">   
                <div class="ui-bar-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow" style="padding:1em;">
                    <div id="map_canvas" style="height:350px;"></div>
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="name">Target Destination:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="target-dest" id="target-dest" value=""  />
                </div>
                <a href="#" id="directions-button" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true">Get Directions</a>
                <div data-role="collapsible" id="instructions-container">
                   <h3>Instructions</h3>
                   <p><div id="instructions-content"></div></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

Put the HTML code in a file map.html and open it directly with Mozilla Firefox (in case you don't want to put it on a server and test it). Otherwise put the file on a server and open it with any browser you want.

Initially you will be asked whether you want to share your current location. After you press the Share button you will see a map with a marker showing your current position. If you click the marker you will see you latitude and longitude.

[image]

[image]

I hope this helps.

Comment: I was a bit familiar with this method.If I have no choice I will use this.  But I was more interested in launching the Google Navigation app (Already installed on android phones) from within the website.  Any clues if that's possible ?

Comment: Would it be possible to get the directions *Without having to enter a location and hit the button * ?